# The hand/pointer mouse cursor changed after a snap refresh. How do I change it back?

Tags: snap, cursor, mouse-pointer

I just did `sudo snap refresh`, and now the pointer/hand mouse cursor changed.

It used to look like a normal mouse pointer, [like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NFhqs.png), but now when I hover over a clickable link or button, the mouse cursor becomes like this.
[image]
(picture of screen because screenshots remove the pointer)

1. **What made it change to this?**
2. **How do I change it back?**

Note that I disabled automatic snap refreshes and refresh them manually because of issues with Chromium.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Install gnome-tweaks by:

```
sudo apt install gnome-tweaks
```

and then go into appearance to change the cursor back to normal (yaru)

if it doesn't work try logging out and in again

Comment: It was already on yaru. I changed it to DMZ-White and that fixed it. Thank you

Comment: I just had the same thing happen to me. I did not change settings, no installs occurred and suddenly I got the hand, while the cursor scheme was Yaru. Will try the re-login thing now. Ubuntu 22.04 btw.

Comment: The most recent snap update caused Firefox v110 to show the mouse hand cursor, and no amount of tweaking or rebooting would fix this. So I re-installed Firefox from the `apt` repository using [these instructions](https://www.omgubuntu.co.uk/2022/04/how-to-install-firefox-deb-apt-ubuntu-22-04). Afterwards I had to go to `about:profiles` to re-install my backup from `~home/snap/firefox` and make it the default. It fixed the cursor issue.

Comment: Update to the above comment. An upgrade to Ubuntu threw out my apt-installed Firefox and shoved the snap version down my throat again. Just now Firefox crashed and the hand pointer suddenly reappeared. *Sigh*