# Firefox snap ignoring Yaru cursor theme on install

Tags: firefox, 22.04, themes, snap, cursor

I recently reinstalled the firefox snap for reasons unrelated to this question. I'm on ubuntu 22.04, and wayland on an amd gpu.

When I did, the newly reinstalled firefox stopped respecting my system cursor theme. My system cursor is set to Yaru, the default, but displays as this in firefox when I hover on something, and a slightly smaller pixelated black pointer otherwise (on one portrait monitor, it is very small and also cropped, despite the same DPI)

[image]
I don't know if this is Adwaita, or what.

I understand that snaps sometimes struggle with this, but firefox normally doesn't have a problem displaying a Yaru mouse pointer, and only started having a problem since I reinstalled the snap. I have another computer with the firefox snap, but left untouched since the original install, and it also displays a Yaru theme cursor fine.

Is there something different about the snap repository package compared to the preinstalled one? Was some configuration deleted during the remove --purge and reinstall? Any ideas?

I have already tried changing my cursor theme in tweaks to DMZ-white, logging out, logging back in, changing it to Yaru, and logging out and in again. Did not fix the issue. Nor did restarting the computer, restarting firefox, or swapping to Xorg.

EDIT: Fixed by [How can I get back the default cursor over links in Ubuntu 22.04 with Firefox snap?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1432707/how-can-i-get-back-the-default-cursor-over-links-in-ubuntu-22-04-with-firefox-sn)

Thank you!

Comment: A search on this site will show you you are asking a question that has been asked many times. Firefox default install is a SNAP package. It will not by default obey rules outside that package. Changes to the Firefox config are required for them to work. Look and see if Firefox has any options of this nature.

Comment: If there a known issue, could you link to it here? The only answered "duplicate" I could find is when using a custom cursor. But this post is about the default Yaru cursor. Previously the Firefox snap package did respect the default Yaru cursor, I have seen this myself personally. Either it's broken upstream for all users or there is some unintentional configuration change that causes this.

Comment: Yes. Additionally, it worked until I reinstalled the snap. Another user experienced a similar issue refreshing the snap, https://askubuntu.com/questions/1299009/the-hand-pointer-mouse-cursor-changed-after-a-snap-refresh-how-do-i-change-it-b?rq=1, but their fix didn't work for me. The question is why the reinstalled snap exhibits different behavior than the original, preinstalled snap.

Comment: answer at: https://askubuntu.com/questions/1432308/firefox-snap-ignoring-yaru-cursor-theme-on-install/1433080#1433080

Answer (score 0):

The problem is "snap". I got the following answer (modified for clarity for myself) from this website: https://itsfoss.com/firefox-quantum-ubuntu/
under the title: **Installing latest Firefox on Linux from its website**

First you need to Uninstall Firefox from "Ubuntu Software" (search for it there under the installed tab).

Download Firefox from:
https://www.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/new/
-in the terminal in /home/aahmed/Downloads/ run: tar xjf firefox-*
-then:
sudo mv ~/Downloads/firefox /opt/firefox
sudo ln -s /opt/firefox/firefox /usr/bin/firefox

You can now start Firefox from the terminal: firefox &

You can gedit the icon under the /home/aahmed/Desktop/firefox_firefox.desktop
and change line 154 to:
Exec=/opt/firefox/firefox %u

and change line 157 to:
Icon=/opt/firefox/browser/chrome/icons/default64.png

Now when you click the icon, Firefox launches without any cursor issues.

Comment: This is simply instructions to manually install firefox. Even if I was to install the non-snap version, the better way to do it would be using the ppa, so that I continue to get updates.

I'm well aware the issue is with the fact that it is a snap, the question is why the snap works in the original install, but stops working when it is reinstalled.

Comment: I didn't reinstall snap. I'm having this problem since I installed Ubuntu 22.04 for the first time ever.

Comment: I had this same problem. `sudo snap remove firefox`, `sudo apt remove firefox`, and `sudo snap install firefox` fixed it for me.

Comment: @zoup To use a ppa refer to this answer: https://askubuntu.com/questions/1399383/how-to-install-firefox-as-a-traditional-deb-package-without-snap-in-ubuntu-22